# Just keep the numbers in a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a variable that contains numbers , letters and special character

```
var variable = '32432 (now) today';
```

and I would like to keep the numbers for my variable looks like this

```
variable = 32432;
```

Comment: Does it always begin the number?  If so `parseInt(variable)`

Comment: If there's inconsistencies in the string, use a regular expression. `var numberPattern = /\d+/g;`

Comment: Where does the string come from? I mean, it is possible to achieve what you're asking, but if you have any control over the data, it's better to refactor the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the number will always be the first part of the string, you can just use parseInt().

```
 console.log(parseInt(variable));
```

or parseFloat if you expect it to be a float:

```
 console.log(parseFloat(variable));
```

If not at the beginning of the string, just remove everything except digits and the decimal point using a regular expression. This expression, /[^\d\.]/gim matches any character that isn't a digit using \d or a decimal point using \.

```
 console.log(variable.replace(/[^\d\.]/gim, ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

`Regex` (regular expressions) are useful in this scenario:

```js
var variable = '32432 (now) today';
var result = /\d+/.exec(variable); // <- \d+ extracts digits

document.write(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user regular expressions to extract number from the string. Something like

```
var str = '32432 (now) today'; 
var regexPattern = /\d+/;
var value = str.match(regexPattern);
```